# How to check if everything in the loop is true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple multiple question form, each question has 4 answers and users must select 1 answer for each question.

So far I can check for an unanswered question and show an error message.

But now if all questions have been answered, I need the form to go to a results page (I assume `window.location`?)

How can I check if all questions have been answered?

```
$('.submit-button').click(function(event){
    $('.validate-message').hide();

    for (var i=1;i<6;i++) {
        var input = $("input[name=q"+i+"]");
        var inputChecked = $("input[name=q"+i+"]:checked");

        if (!inputChecked.val()) { //if an answer is not selected for a question
            $(input).parents('fieldset').append('<div class="validate-message" style="color:red;">Please choose an answer!</div>');

        } else { // if an answer is selected for a question
        }
    }       
    return false;          
});
```

Comment: Don't use the submit button's onclick listener, use the form's onsubmit listener. Forms can be submitted without clicking their submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a boolean variable:

```
$('.submit-button').click(function(event){
    var noErrors = true;  // default to no errors

    $('.validate-message').hide();

    for (var i=1;i<6;i++) {
        var input = $("input[name=q"+i+"]");
        var inputChecked = $("input[name=q"+i+"]:checked");

        if (!inputChecked.val()) { //if an answer is not selected for a question
            noErrors = false;  // an error was found, set noErrors to false
            $(input).parents('fieldset').append('<div class="validate-message" style="color:red;">Please choose an answer!</div>');

        } else { // if an answer is selected for a question
        }
    }       

    if(noErrors) // do stuff

    return false;          
});
```

Comment: thanks buddy - im over thinking per usual. will tick this answer when the time is up.

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, here's a plain javascript solution.

Assuming HTML something like the following:

```
<form id="f0" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
  <div>
    <p>Question 1.<br>
      A<input type="radio" value="A" name="q1"><br>
      B<input type="radio" value="B" name="q1"><br>
      C<input type="radio" value="C" name="q1"><br>
      D<input type="radio" value="D" name="q1"><br>
    </p>
    <p>Question 2.<br>
      A<input type="radio" value="A" name="q2"><br>
      B<input type="radio" value="B" name="q2"><br>
      C<input type="radio" value="C" name="q2"><br>
      D<input type="radio" value="D" name="q2"><br>
    </p>
    <input type="reset"  value="Clear answers">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit answers">
  </div>
</form>
```

A function to validate that each question has been answered is:

```
function validateForm(form) {

  var control, controls = form.elements;
  var visited = {};
  var name, radios;

  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    control = controls[i];
    name = control.name;

    if (control.type == 'radio' && name && !visited.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      visited[name] = false;
      radios = form[name];

      for (j=0, jLen=radios.length; j<jLen; j++) {
        visited[name] = visited[name] || radios[j].checked;
      }

      if (!visited[name]) {
        // Question hasn't been answered, cancel submit and do whatever
        alert('There are unanswered questions for ' + name);
        return false;
      }
    }
    // Validation for other controls
    // ...
  }
}
```